# I cant get this code to work in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
keepgoing = True
num1 = int(input("Enter a Number"))
num2 = int(input("Enter a Number"))
bignums = 0
smallnums = 0
counter = 0

while keepgoing:

    if num1 > num2:
        bignums = bignums + num1
        smallnums = smallnums + num2
    else:
        bignums = bignums + num2
        smallnums = smallnums + num1

    counter + 1

    if num1 == 0:
        keepgoing = False


print (bignums / counter)
print (smallnums / counter)
```

The program i am writing:
Write a program that enters pairs of numbers until the first number in the pair is 0. The program will add the smallest number to a total for smaller numbers, the largest number to a total for the largest numbers. After exit from the loop, it will print the average of the smaller numbers, the average of the higher numbers, and the highest and lowest numbers entered.

I think i did everything right, but it wont end/exit the loop when you type "0". Also i don't know how to make it show the highest and lowest number. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the assignment, you have to enter numbers in every iteration of the loop. Now your program just goes into an infinite loop. You can print something inside your loop if you're not sure what's going on

Comment: You never change `num1` in the loop so if `num1` is not 0 this will enter an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this as suggested by @Joseph keep the entry for numbers inside the loop:

```
keepgoing = True

bignums = 0
smallnums = 0
counter = 0

while keepgoing:

    num1 = int(input("Enter a First Number"))
    num2 = int(input("Enter a Second Number"))

    if num1 > num2:
        bignums = bignums + num1
        smallnums = smallnums + num2
    else:
        bignums = bignums + num2
        smallnums = smallnums + num1

    counter += 1

    if num1 == 0:
        keepgoing = False


    print "Average of big numbers", bignums / counter
    print "Average of small numbers", smallnums / counter
```

Also would be good if you handle cases like what will happen if the user enters both the numbers as same. Let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is Num1 never changes so if you put something other then zero it would get stuck. you can change
`keepgoing = false`

to

```
break
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a Number"))
num2 = int(input("Enter a Number"))
```

must be inside the loop as well for the application to terminate.